# how to get words count from MS Word without carriage return and hidden text using c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, word-count

Is that possible to get the words count from the MS Word without the carriage return and hidden text in c#.. I want to get the words count which is shown in Ms word document..
i am using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` namespace and
Using `ActiveDocument.Words.Count`.. i am getting all the count including the carriage return.. How to get that word count without carriage and hidden text..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works..

```
int stWordCount = wordobj.ActiveDocument.ComputeStatistics(Word.WdStatistic.wdStatisticWords);
```